# how change kivy's widget's settings using python script?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, widget

how could i change settings of a widget declared in a kivy file using its own python class?
example:

kv file:

```
<Button>:
Button:
    name:'btn'
    text:'yes'
    on_press:doet()
```

py file:

```
class Button(self):
    def doet():
        btn.text='nope'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by setting an ID to the button. All you got to do is add `id: "btn"` to your .kv file and you could access this through `self.ids.btn.text` in your .py file. So it must look like this:

.kv

```
<Button>
    Button:
        id:'btn'
        text:'yes'
        on_press: root.doet()
```

.py

```
class Button:
    def doet(self):
        self.ids.btn.text='nope'
```